# Network between 2 computers for web development

Tags: networking

I have 2 laptop computers (with Windows 7), both connected to the same Wifi, I want to set up a network between them so I can code in my text editor on the first one, and see the results displaying in real time in the navigator of the second one, that would be a real time saving way of coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of XAMMP? https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
This is great for local testing as well as hopefully meeting your criteria.
Run XAMMP on your coding pc, then you will be able to connect to the XAMMP server via local IP address on your other PC.

I use XAMMP a lot for local web development. 
The only issue is you would have to move what ever your using on to your local server (PHP files, images, and MYSQL databases.)

Comment: Sure i know XAMMP, is it possible to view what am i coding in my 1st computer ( coding ) from my 2nd computer ?

Comment: Yes that is correct - as long as you're on the same local network then you will be able to connect to the xammp server. For example:
192.168.0.1/projectfolder/index.php
that would connect you to your xammp server

Comment: Can you suggest a tutorial on how to set the local network ?

Comment: And if i do so, i have to refresh everytime in my 2nd computer, right ?

Comment: I believe this video should do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf_BBBTfxm0

Correct. You would have to hit refresh on your page to see updates.

Comment: Yes, i've tested and it works fine, thank you sir :) do you know any way to let the second computer refresh the page in like 5 secondes ?

Comment: No problem - I found a link to a google chrome extension that seems like it should do what you need it to do. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=en

Comment: Thank you again sir, i really apreciate it.

Comment: Absolutely no problem!